# Multilingual App Toolkit with continuous integration

Tags: c#, msbuild, win-universal-app, multilingual-app-toolkit

In my UWP project I uses [Multilingual App Toolkit](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6dab9154-a7e1-46e4-bbfa-18b5e81df520), but there are a problem because the build on Visual Studio Team Services generate error MSB4019: *The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Multilingual App Toolkit\v4.0\Microsoft.Multilingual.PriResources.targets* was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. 
Is there any way to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score -1):

Can you go to *Control Panel* -> *Programs and Features* and check, which version of Multilingual Toolkit you have installed.

I just had the same error after installing MAT and it turned out to be version 3.1 instead of 4.0. Maybe you have both version installed?

Try to deinstall all versions of MAT and reinstall latest version from [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6dab9154-a7e1-46e4-bbfa-18b5e81df520).